# How should i read an assignment?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I'm studying C++ as a beginner and my book explain me what is assignment but i can't understand a little concept that the book is trying to make me understand:

```
int a = 3; // a starts out with the value 3
a = a + 7; // a gets the value of a + 7 (that is, 10)
```

What my book says is: the last assignment deserves notice.First of all it clearly shows that = doesn't mean equals-clearly, a doesn't equal to a + 7.It means assignment, that is, to place a new value in a variable. What does it mean ? how should i read an assignment? 
For example: 
     a = a + 7; // should i read it as: a is equal to a + 7 ?

Comment: In `int a = 3;` it's technically not an assignment, but an *initialization*.

Comment: Read it as "assign (the value of) `a+7` to (the variable) `a`". Don't read it as "is equal to" since (as your book says) it doesn't mean "equals", it means "assignment".

Comment: I read it like: "Make **a** equal to **a + 7**". Actually (showing my BASIC heritage) in my head its "**LET a = a + 7**" (as in LET THERE BE LIGHT!).

Answer (score 3):

The code might be expanded in following way:

```
int a; // declaration of the variable.        a has undefined value.
a = 3; // Assign the value 3 to a.            a is 3.
a = a + 7; // Assign value of (a + 7) to a.   a is 10.
```

The expression (a + 7) is evaluated first and the value of (3 + 7) is assigned to a.

The token = is used for assignment and doesn't have anything to do with equality.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment means that the right-hand side (rhs) will be evaluated to a single value, then assigned to the left-hand side (lhs)

```
a = a + 7;
```

Now, rhs --> `a` + 7 --> 3 + 7 --> 10, now we have a single value, and will assign 10 to `a`

Answer (score 2):

In C++ **=** is the assignment operator. **==** is the equality operator.

Read the chapter about *operator precence* (the order in which operators performs operations on its operands).

= (the assignment operator) is a binary operator, has lowest precedence (that is the reason first a+7 operation is performed) and it ***assigns the result of an expression on its right side to the variable on its left side***.

For, `a = a + 7`, never read it *as a equals* `a + 7`, but make habit of reading it as `a` ***gets assigned the value of*** `a + 7` (or whatever the expression) is.

The = also replaces the exiting value of variable on left side (`a`) with the result of expression on right side ( `a + 7`).